# Что это за конструкция

Tags: c

начал изучать си и не могу понять такую конструкцию:

```
#ifndef __int64
#ifdef __INT64_TYPE__
#define __int64 __INT64_TYPE__
#endif
/* On some architectures neither of these may be defined - if so, fall
 through and error out if used. */
#endif
```

а также:

```
typedef struct __fpos_t_struct {
  unsigned __int64 __pos;
  /*
   * this structure is equivalent to an mbstate_t, but we're not
   * allowed to actually define the type name `mbstate_t' within
   * stdio.h
   */
  struct {
    unsigned int __state1, __state2;
  } __mbstate;
} fpos_t;
```

Это структура в структуре или что вообще?

Comment: Да, анонимная структура с именем `__mbstate`

Comment: а зачем делать структуру в структуре?

Comment: Для удобства компоновки данных вероятно..

Comment: Затем, что эта структура больше нигде никому не нужна. Ее сделали безымянной и, поэтому, ее пришлось поместить внутрь.

Comment: Например, для того чтобы был удобный интерфейс с функциями, работающими с многобайтными символами (`mbstate_t` именно из этой области. Почему авторы не хотят явно включать ее в stdio -- не знаю)

Comment: Спасибо всем. А встречал ли кто-нибудь более вложенные конструкции?-хотелось бы глянуть

Comment: Посмотрите заголовки для имплементации  TCP/IP стека.

Comment: а где можно примерно это глянуть? Ссылку там.например